# Ubuntu 18.04 update problem

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, updates, gnupg

Everytime I try `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update`, system returns following errors:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease           
Hit:4 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease       
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B] 
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease           
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551 Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction to fix this problem. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same today.

here's what you do:

1. Download this : https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

(chrome new version, you can get it yourself by googling chrome)

2. Close Chrome.
3. Open "Software and Sources", go to the "Sources" tab
4. Remove (or disable if you wish to re-enable it at a later time) the Google source (type your password) and close the window
5. Allow "Software and Sources" to reload sources
6. Go into Software Center, go to "Installed"
7. Find Chrome, uninstall it.
8. Close software and sources
9. Open a terminal, type :

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`
10. Close the terminal and go to your downloads folder and double click the file "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" (this will open Software Center)
11. Click Install

you can now open chrome back up. all your tabs and saved passwords ect are still there.

Comment: Ok, it works on 16.04 LTS, but only if I disable Google repositories.

Comment: Please mark as duplicate rather than copy and paste the same answer over and over.

Comment: I answered here first because I thought this question was the first one asked. they all poped up relatively at the same time. since this question is the one that is most likely doomed to become the duplicate of the other I'm safeguarding my answer before it does. I can delete here if that's really what people want....