# What to do with KEYEXPIRED 1555048520 on updating Google Chrome and Earth repositories?

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, google-chrome, google-earth

When I run `sudo apt-get update` on my fully updated Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS I get the following errors about Google repositories:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
Err:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Err:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg 
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The `apt-key list` returns:

```
pub   1024D/7FAC5991 2007-03-08
uid                  Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   2048g/C07CB649 2007-03-08

pub   4096R/D38B4796 2016-04-12
uid                  Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   4096R/997C215E 2017-01-24 [expires: 2020-01-24]
```

Removing Google keys and packages with

```
sudo apt-key del D38B4796
sudo apt-key del 7FAC5991
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable 
sudo apt purge google-earth-pro-stable
sudo apt purge google-earth-stable
```

and reinstalling packages with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

wget https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

does not help.

Executing command from https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ :

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

does not help.

How should I fix it?

What else I did:
1. sent feedback from Google Chrome with *Help → Report an Issue*.
2. sent feedback from Google Earth using *Help → Send feedback*.
3. created thread on [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4039457?hl=en)

Comment: has been Reported in AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551

Comment: @ChrisdeJager Thank you! I see, but here it is 16.04 and other key. Hope that official universal solution will become available soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133261/ubuntu-18-04-update-problem/1133270#1133270

Comment: ...at least that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fixed on Google's end now, so you can update normally through apt without workarounds.

(Sorry, can't comment due to <50 reputation.)

Answer (score 3):

Current status on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

- Google Chrome repository updated successfully.
- Google Earth repository updated successfully.

---

If you still have issues - then remove GPG keys and re-add GPG key into the system with

```
sudo apt-key del D38B4796
sudo apt-key del 7FAC5991
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

or

```
sudo apt-key net-update
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D38B4796
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7FAC5991
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
```

and update package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had to remove *chrome-remote-desktop* with

```
sudo apt purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

to avoid leftover complains at update runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving it here... Similar error occurs in Azure DSVM when upgrading it. Following will update the keys

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
```