# Choosing Repositorie error

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04
On Choosing an Repository I have 3 choices for this country and all gave this error.

Could not download all repository indexes

> `The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.`
>
> `An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Can some one help to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with KEYEXPIRED 1555048520 on updating Google Chrome and Earth repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133273/what-to-do-with-keyexpired-1555048520-on-updating-google-chrome-and-earth-reposi) But are you sure that Google have repositories for Raspberry (ARM CPU)?